# Image caption not rendering on some images - Shapely theme

Tags: captions

I'm using Shapely theme v1.0.5 on top of Wordpress v4.7.1. I'm writing an article and everything was fine, until I noticed two images didn't have their captions rendered, while the others rendered correctly.

[image: Captions showing correctly] Captions showing correctly

[image: Captions not rendered] Captions not rendered

I tried changing the caption to pass as an atribute, adding caption="" on the shortcode but it didn't render either. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you check the images in the media library? Do they have their captions set in the library?

Comment: Yes, the caption appear on the media library.

Comment: This is strange. If the title/caption of an image is set, it should be automatically added. Have you tried to manually set the caption in your post's content?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean? Rewriting the shortcode on the edit page?

Comment: Yes. I want to know if wordpress has problem processing the shortcode, or it simply can't insert the shortcode in the content.

Comment: Okay so I decided to switch to the visual editor (I was using the text editor editing the html code) to see how things were there and the captions were actually properly rendered. I hit publish and on the page everything is alright now. Should I post this as the answer?

Comment: Yes please, so the future visitors may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted in a comment, it turned out to be a glitch. I was using the text editor to edit the html of the page and decided to switch to the visual editor to check things. It turns out that the captions were properly rendered on the visual editor and when I published it the actual page had everything properly rendered.